# Pinterest RSS Formatting

Tags: rss, format, pinterest

Anyone know how to re-formatting pinterest rss? I use this http://www.pinterest.com/username/feed.rss but it kind of like bad format, then I can't parsing into rssinclude.com.

Comment: What's not valid about this feed? It works fine for [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com/) and [Feed validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

Comment: @JulienGenestoux Sorry, I think I need a kind of beautify rss formatter.